# Error to generate pdf. Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdflatex, pylatex

I'm facing the same problem as [PyLaTeX: pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601901/pylatex-pylatex-errors-compilererror-no-latex-compiler-was-found) but I have not found an answer yet. I´m using Windows and I have the `MixTex` and `pylatex` packages installed.

I'm trying first this to then added to other code but is not runnig.

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection
from pylatex.utils import italic
import pdflatex

def document(doc):
    geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "10cm"}
    doc =Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)
    
    with doc.create(Section('Results')):
         doc.append('Something')
    doc.generate_pdf('Results', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdfLaTeX')
    tex = doc.dumps()
```

I would like to get some help here. The error is the same:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "generalcode.py", in validation
    doc.generate_pdf('Resultados', clean_tex=False, compiler='pdfLaTeX')
  File "C:Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pylatex\document.py", in generate_pdf
    raise(CompilerError(
pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have latex installed? Open a command prompt and type `pdflatex --version`. What output do you get?

Comment: I have the last version `pdflatex==0.1.3` in python and I installed MixTex after install `pylatex` packages in python so I think it should be running but is not.

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `pdflatex --version`. What output do you get? If `pdflatex` is not accessible on the path, python could think that you don't have it installed. If this is the case, add the directory of your `pdflatex` executable to the path and restart python

Comment: I use pip freeze to check it but using what you comment I get `bash: pdflatex: command not found`.

Comment: I solved. I had to restart python. I had not close the command prompt after the installation of `MixTex` and that was why I was having that issue. As @PranavHosangadi said , when you put `pdflatex --version`. it have to show the path of the pdflatex, if not maybe you have not restarted python yet after installing Latex.